# Rounded Corners Not Displaying in Safari

Tags: css, html, safari

I work on a PC so I hadn't realized I was having this problem. Basically, the rounded corners of my container are not displaying in safari, which is strange because I believe the code I used is compatible with Safari. Any input on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my container code:

```
.container {
  clear: both;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 940px;
  background: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90; /* the stack order: displayed under ribbon rectangle (100) */
/*   overflow-x: hidden; */
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

And then my website is basically wrapped in it:

```
<div class="container">
    WEBSITE
</div>
```

If you have safari, you can view the issue [here](http://www.noellesnotes.com).

Comment: At the very least you are missing the unprefixed variant of `border-radius`.

Comment: What version of Safari?

Comment: Im running safari, although im running it on win 8, it works fine for me

Comment: @Noelle - Just add missing border-radius: 10px;

Comment: @Noelle Also for Box Shadow > add box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

Comment: SRK , the default CSS for border radius in safari is -webkit-border-radius:

Comment: @AnaMaria - prefix no longer needed from Safari version 5+

Comment: @srk, do you have a link where you got that from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you've got all the prefixed versions of `border-radius`, but you haven't got the standard un-prefixed version.

You need to add `border-radius: 10px;`

Yes, Safari is a Webkit browser, so you might think that `-webkit-border-radius` should work, but the prefixed version is only supposed to exist while the style is experimental. Once it's become a standard, the browsers are supposed to drop support for the prefixed version and only support the standard version.

`border-radius` became a standard a long time ago, so all browsers should now support the standard version without a prefix. Some browsers do still support their prefix, but they could drop support in any version.

The same applies to `box-shadow`, and to every other CSS style -- if you are declaring prefixes, you should also always declare the un-prefixed standard version too.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Apple's CSS reference site for developers only makes note of the -webkit-border-radius property. https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html

Comment: I checked a couple of other sources. They do mention that in Safari 5+ you need to use the border-radius property. So +1 to you

Comment: @AnaMaria - the documentation is out of date, because Safari has supported the unprefixed version for *ages*. Plus even if it does work in Safari, the code given in the question excludes IE users entirely due to the lack of using the standard syntax.

Comment: Yup. I agree. Apple sucks

Answer (score 0):

Consider the answer provided by @Spudley ,in case if it doesn't solve the problem

Few things you can do:

1)**Check your Safari Version**

As @Adrift pointed out in the comments ,it might be a compatibility problem.

2)A **non-visible character** might be present in your css code

This problem occurs often thus making the programmers struggling for hours to find the problem.Try writing the code into another file or use some good editor which shows the hidden characters.